# sql query : conversion failed to int

Tags: mysql, sql, matlab, adodb

I am trying to retrieve data from a database with an open source MATLAB [toolbox](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29615-adodb-tools/content/adodb/html/adodb_tutorial_script.html) ,

```
   sql = ['SELECT [gateId],[dsum] FROM [TEMPO].[dbo].', 'Data', ' WHERE [gateId]=', '5433'];
   f = adodb_query(con,sql);
```

now after a while I get an error that

> > Description: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'gateId' to data type int.

I tried only using just `SELECT [dsum] FROM` in the query but i was still getting the error which meant the error is in this `' WHERE [gateId]=', '5433'` part , it is failing to convert it into int, I have tried this toolbox for the same database container but with different query and It works fine but somehow for this I am getting this error. Does anyone has any idea what is causing this ?

Answer (score 0):

the error is actually way before that, the single `'` that starts the string in MATLAB ends it also:

```
sql = ['SELECT [gateId],[dsum] FROM [TEMPO].[dbo].', 'Data', ' WHERE [gateId]=', '5433'];
```

is in MATLAB

```
sql = ['SELECT [gateId],[dsum] FROM [TEMPO].[dbo].DataWHERE [gateId]=5433'];
```

you cann see that as in MATLAB the color of the string part is violett and the commas are black as they are only MATLAB code. To use `'` in a string you have to make 2 of them in a row:

```
sql = [' SELECT [gateId],[dsum] FROM [TEMPO].[dbo].'', ''Data'', '' WHERE [gateId]='', ''5433'' '];
```

Comment: `sql = ['SELECT [gateId],[dsum] FROM [TEMPO].[dbo].', 'Data', ' WHERE [gateId]=', '5433']` is same as `sql = ['SELECT [gateId],[dsum] FROM [TEMPO].[dbo].DataWHERE [gateId]=5433']` it wont make a difference , MATLAB automatically concatenates the whole query as a string for the first one

Comment: oh i thought you wanted to get the `'` to sql... have you tried `WH‌​ERE  gateId = 5433`